# Retrieve last 3 years of data with custom date

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my query:

`mysql> select * from jobs where datediff(now(),str_to_date(last_modified,'%M %d,%Y'))>=1095;`

I get 0 results

mysql> select max(last_modified) from jobs;

```
+--------------------+
| max(last_modified) |
+--------------------+
| 9/9/2013           |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)

mysql>
```

It doesn't seem to be working to well and Im not sure why. `I think it has to do with the original formatting of the last_modified column`

**UPDATE**

```
mysql> select distinct(last_modified) from jobs where datediff(now(),str_to_date(last_modified,'%m/%d/%Y'))>=1095 limit 10;

+---------------+
| last_modified |
+---------------+
| 12/4/2003     |
| 12/5/2003     |
| 12/6/2003     |
| 12/8/2003     |
| 12/9/2003     |
| 12/10/2003    |
| 12/11/2003    |
| 12/12/2003    |
| 12/13/2003    |
| 12/14/2003    |
+---------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: but doesnt datediff returns the difference (in days) between 2 dates? implying it does then your query will always return zero results unless the difference in days its more than 1095 and even if it is more than that itll return ALL the rows.

Comment: @ivan ok then how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have any column with dates? or whats your table structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str_to_date(last_modified,'%m/%d/%Y')` instead of `str_to_date(last_modified,'%M %d,%Y')`

Comment: You are selecting records from three years old and older, place <= into request in order to select new records up to three years.